# CS GO server error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, steam

As a part of my self-training, where I try to learn anything about VPS's, I wanted to start my own small CS:GO server.

I was using multiple tutorials available in the web, but none of those answers my question about the error which is occuring every time, no matter which tutorial I use.

Server details:

VPS from OVHcloud, 1vC, 2 GB operational memory, 40 GB disk space, Ubuntu 22.04

Steps that I performed:

As a root, created a steam user:
`sudo useradd -m steam sudo passwd steam`

Went into the folder
`cd /home/steam`

Installed the dependencies required to run SteamCMD
`sudo apt-get install lib32gcc-s1`

Created a directory for SteamCMD and switched to it
`mkdir ~/Steam && cd ~/Steam`

Downloaded and unzipped the SteamCMD
`wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz`

`tar xf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz`

Created the install folder
`force_install_dir ./csgo`

Logged as anonymous
`login anonymous`

Updated the app to download the CS GO server files
`app_update 740 validate`

Created an startserver.sh file with following commands inside:
`./srcds_run -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2 +sv_setsteamaccount XXXXXX -net_port_tryz` (replacing XXX with my token)

Tried to run the .sh file mentioned in pt. 9, and getting this error:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/steam/cs_go/bin:/home/steam/cs_go:/home/steam/cs_go/bin: Failed to open libtier0.so (/home/steam/cs_go/bin/libgcc_s.so.1: version GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by /lib32/libstdc++.so.6))`

When I run the .sh script to run the server, I always get the same error, no matter which tutorial I use

As my knowledge about managing/setting VPS servers over SSH is almost close to 0, it's possible that I had the answer just in front of my eyes, but I didn't know that.

Everything that is related to this error should be installed, but it seems that something is wrong with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Any help would be largely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Followed tutorials step by step

Installed all necessary libraries (I hope so)

Checked the official SteamCMD wiki

Expectation: to run the server

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 lsb-core
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt install build-essential
```

[Link](https://nodetwelve.com/csgo-sourcemod-metamod-issues-on-ubuntu-21-04/)

Comment: Hello,

Unfortunately I get the same output with the error. Third command `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` returns `Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1`. Installing the mentioned package does nothing for solving my problem as well.

Comment: Omit that one, and does it work?

Comment: Commands from the 1st answer do not result in any changes, still the same error regarding LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

After installing the required libraries as [@sinclair](https://askubuntu.com/a/1467407/1695360) pointed out, rename or remove the included *libgcc_s.so.1* file inside the server's *bin* directory.

```
mv /home/steam/cs_go/bin/libgcc_s.so.1 /home/steam/cs_go/bin/libgcc_s.so.1.old
```

Comment: This allowed me to finally run the server. Nevertheless, I cannot connect to it, as it demand to restart it. `sudo reboot` does not help, so I assume it has to be done via SteamCMD? I cannot find anything related to it in the web.

Comment: What's the exact error message? I'm assuming the server is prompting you to update it. If that is the case, run _steamcmd_ and type in the following commands:
`force_install_dir CSGO_SERVER_DIR` `login anonymous` `app_update 740`.
Where CSGO_SERVER_DIR is the path to your server (i.e ./csgo). Updating the server can be automated in the launch script: [link](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive/Dedicated_Servers#Linux_Scripts).